Why is the derivative of the distance between two points not their relative velocity?
I have a problems where I wish to calculate the relative velocity between two objects, and the answer to the problems says that a component of the velocity is second order and hence can be dropped. This confused me.
The problem being: "Six bugs are placed at the vertices of a regular hexagon with side length s. At time t = 0 each bug starts moving directly towards the next with speed v. At what time do they collide?".
The answer says: "We can first do this by considering how the distance between adjacent bugs changes in an infinitesimal time dt. The first bug moves a distance v dt towards the second. The second moves a
distance ( 3/2)v dt to the side, and a distance (v/2) dt directly away from the first. The side-to-side motion doesn’t contribute to the change in distance (one can use the Pythagorean theorem and binomial theorem to show it is second order, and hence negligible for infinitesimals), so we ignore it. Then the rate of change of distance between the bugs is just v − v/2 = v/2, so the bugs meet at t = 2s/v."
I'm having trouble understanding why the side motion is neglected and how the Pythagorean theorem and binomial theorem may be used to show it is second order?
This problem is great example, but I've encountered similar things multiple times, so to generalise:
Why is the relative velocity between two objects only dependant between the components of velocities of the two objects, along the line joining the two objects?
In other words, why is the derivative of the distance between two points not the relative velocity?

Where did you find this problem? Are you sure it is a credible source? I am not convinced that the bugs collide at all! I am not convinced that after $dt$, the distance between a bug and its next is anything other than $s$.

I found it on preparatory handouts for physics competitions. It’s problem 18 here: https://knzhou.github.io/handouts/M1Sol.pdf.
The guy who wrote it went to mit, cambridge and oxford so I trust him lol

My mistake! Thanks for sharing the source.

This is (mathematically) straight-forward if you just compute the time-derivative of the distance directly. If the instantaneous positions of the two particles are $\vec{r}_1$ and $\vec{r}_2$, and $r=\lVert\vec{r}\rVert = \lVert \vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2\rVert$ is the instantaneous distance between them, then
\begin{align}
\frac{dr}{dt}
&=
\frac{d}{dt}\sqrt{\lVert \vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2\rVert^2}
\\&=
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\lVert \vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2\rVert^2}}\frac{d}{dt}\lVert \vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2\rVert^2
\\&=\frac{1}{2r}\frac{d}{dt}\left(\left(\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2\right)\cdot\left(\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2\right)\right)
\\&=
\frac{1}{2r}\left(
2\left(\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2\right)\cdot\frac{d}{dt}\left(\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2\right)
\right)
\\&=
\frac{\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2}{\lVert \vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2\rVert}\cdot
\frac{d}{dt}(\vec{r}_1-\vec{r}_2)
\\&=
\frac{\vec{r}}{\lVert \vec{r}\rVert}\cdot
\frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}
\,,
\end{align}
which is exactly the component of the relative velocity along the direction joining the two particles.
(To get to the second line, we used the chain rule. To get to the third line, we recognize that the squared-norm of a vector is the dot product of that vector with itself. To get to the next line, we just used the product rule (which works for dot products just fine), noticing that the two terms we get from the product rule are the same.)
